# How to call Azure AD Secured Azure Functions from ReactJS Application

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Following this article : https://cuteprogramming.wordpress.com/2019/01/02/authenticate-an-azure-function-with-azure-active-directory/. I have created an Azure AD Secured Azure Function using a an Azure AD Application (defined by a client id, issuer url, client secret, ..)

But I do not have any idea how to call it from my reactjs code

Do I have to perform to 2 successive http calls : one to get the access token and then a second one to reach my azure function as described in the postman example (in the above article) ?

In this case, the details of the Azure AD Application (client id, secret id,...) can be retrieved from the js code using the browser developer tool and can be then used by anyone to access my azure function. Is it really secure or do I miss something ?

How can I call my azure function from my react application in a secure way (I want my azure function to be only accessible by my react application) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access Azure function app projected by Azure AD in react application, please refer to the following steps

1. Integrate Azure AD auth in your react application with [Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow). After doing that, when users access your application, they need to enter their AD account to get access token
2. Client exchanges this `accessToken` for an 'App Service Token'. It does this by making a POST to `https://{app}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad` with the content `{ "access_token" : "{token from Facebook}" }`. This will return back an `authenticationToken`
3. Use that `authenticationToken` in a header named `x-zumo-auth`. Make all requests to your function app using that header.

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#authentication-flow). Besides, regarding how to integrate Azure AD, please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-core-samples/react-sample-app) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-overview)